# How to implement ListView Pagination from SQLite database in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, pagination

I want to implement List-View from SQLite Database that i have done. But right now i want to implement pagination on List View setOnScrollListener.First time I'm displaying first 50 records after that when I scroll at the end of list run the progress bar some amount of second and after stop the progress bar another next 50 records append to the list.I'm trying lot of time since 5 days working on List View Pagination but it is not working properly.Can some one help me to resolve this issue.

Here is my code .

```
listView.addFooterView(footer);
        // Implementing scroll refresh
        listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstItem, int visibleItemCount, final int totalItems) {
                //Log.e("Get position", "--firstItem:" + firstItem + "  visibleItemCount:" + visibleItemCount + "  totalItems:" + totalItems + "  pageCount:" + pageCount);
                int total = firstItem + visibleItemCount;

               Log.e("", "onScroll LocalPages=" + LocalPages);
                // Total array list i have so it
                if (pageCount < LocalPages) {

                    if (total == totalItems) {

                        // Execute some code after 8 seconds have passed
                        Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                        {
                            public void run()
                            {
                                listView.addFooterView(footer);
                                OFFSET = pageCount * 50 ;
                                //Log.e("","After OFFSET pageCount =" + pageCount + "  OFFSET value ="+OFFSET);
                                List<All_Post> allDesc = dbhelper.getAllDescriptions(OFFSET);
                                for (All_Post all_Post : allDesc)
                                {
                                    descArray.add(all_Post);
                                }
                                if(adapter != null)
                                {
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                    listView.setSelection(totalItems);

                                    pageCount += 1;
                                    Log.e("","  pageCount =" + pageCount + " LocalPages="+LocalPages);

                                }
                            }
                        }, 2000);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("hide footer", "footer hide");
                    listView.removeFooterView(footer);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: "I'm trying lot of time since 5 days working on List View Pagination but it is not working properly." it was on Mar 23 when you were working on it for 5 days, today is Mar 29 so you are working on it for more that 10 days now, i already gave you two working solutions, so what do you expect from SO if you dont want to accept it?

Comment: you can use "pull to refresh" with OnScrollListener

Comment: Yes I know it . I don't want to use SimpleCursorAdapter right now.Because i already use Array-adapter and lot of code in their and right now I can't change.

Comment: @vaibhav rockstar : is it possible to use pull to refresh with LIMIT and OFFSET query

Comment: ok, your choice, if you want to fight with it for another week or month...

Comment: Ok give me some code where you work on ListView Pagination from SQLite database in Android with load more progress bar add footerView of ListView.

Comment: i already gave you a working code, but it seems that you didn't even try it... so...

Comment: yes, You can do this with pull to refresh with LIMIT and OFFSET query

Comment: @ pskink : I don't understand how to use your code? Can you please give me example how to use http://pastebin.com/RPEyRAsk

Comment: so i was right: you didn't even tried it...: `SCA sca = new SCA(...); yourListView.setAdapter(sca);`

Comment: But what about my already use Array-adapter  ArrayAdapter<All_Post> and lot of code. Code line is above 2000.So that's why I'm not able to use your codes in my app.

Comment: thats why, you are using the BAD adapter when dealing with sqlite db, dont use `ArrayAdapter`, always use some sort of `CursorAdapter`

Comment: Yes you are right , but 12 to 17 contents(Text images , images , scroll-view , buttons etc...) added in my List-view Item. So right now I can't change .So what can I do right now.

Comment: i have no idea what you are talking about.. what "12 to 17 contents"?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for following approach.

```
                        // create one final list
                        final ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
                        temp.addAll(previous_data);

                        // call fxn for getting new value
                        // call your database query

                        // add new data into list
                        temp.addAll(new_Data);
                        // intailize static list of adapter showing data
                        // add data into list.
                        ActivityName.MainList = temp;

                         mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

with your code also... thanks