# Is it possible to fetch data only as much as is needed to be displayed on the current screen?

Tags: android, sqlite, webview

I have HTML pages stored in local DB(SQLite) and I would like to use it for offline viewing in an android app using `webview`.

Now, my data is stored as section wise that belong to a book. When user requests to view the book I fetch all sections that belong to that particular book, loop over them to string them together and then show it as one whole book(HTML/CSS/JQ/JS)

Some books tend to be about 5MB and it takes time to display on the screen. I read here on SO that this can't be improved as my data is not simply text but contains HTML etc that needs to be processed according to CSS etc.

Is it possible to display just 1 or 2MBs or few sections of the book and then fetch the rest of the data only if user scrolls down ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at pagination ,  [this would be a great starting point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36276312/how-to-implement-listview-pagination-from-sqlite-database-in-android)